# Hesitate to drop a feature

Tags: feature-selection, correlation

I used to tried making a fake correlation in my mocking dataset and found that if the score is more than `0.5` I can reduce feature to avoid [singularity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14813884/correlated-features-and-classification-accuracy)

In the given example they are many correlated variables. Therefore I am thinking about dimensionality reduction. The one feature here that I plan to remove is `Hum-6D05` because it has strong correlation between `Hum-6D12, Hum-6F04, and Hum-6F14`

**Question:**
Am I correct?
Any comment or advice are welcomed

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That isn't easy to answer, as it highly depends on your taks. The only time where it is definitely recommended to remove a feature is when two attributes correlate perfectly (e.g. price and tax of a product).

Removing attributes that do not correlate perfectly could worsen your accuracy as **information gets lost**. But keeping them could affect the computation time. If you don't worry about computation time, I would highly recommend you to **keep** every bit of information about the data.

If you are concerned about overfitting there are way better techniques such as regularization to solve this problem.

*Note:* Dimensionality reduction is mostly used to visualize high dimensional data, so that a human eye can detect patterns. For example by shrinking the dimension to 3D or even 2D one could observe an exponential dependency.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for your answer. IMO temperature and humidity might has a direct correlation. That's why I would like to confirm my plan before proceed.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't comment on the answer above, so I would like to address, that that answer isn't quite correct. Correlation != Collinearity. Multicollinearity only belongs to multiple regression. If your model uses something different than multiple regression don't look for multicollinearity. Look at https://www.quora.com/In-statistics-what-is-the-difference-between-collinearity-and-correlation for correlation vs. collinearity

Answer (score 1):

The formal name for your concern is "multicollinearity".  This can be a concern in statistically based techniques.  There are formal tests that you can perform to assess multicollinearity like `Variation Inflation Factor`.

That said, many machine learning techniques are indeed not that sensitive to multicollinearity, so it may not matter if for example, you were training a neural network.

To answer your direct question, the terms you highlight are probably not so correlated that I would remove them.

HTH